# Firebase .orderByChild().on runs more and more times every time it is called

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, infinite

I'm creating a guest list program that stores the guest list in Firebase RTDB and when I check people in and out my function runs several times more than it is supposed to. I've sent alerts to the console so I know how many times it has run. I have separate functions for both check in and check out operations so it may be that I am calling my db too many times?

```
 //-------------------- Check In and Check In Helper Functions -------------------------

    //Helper Function to Grab current List index
    function printArray() {
  

    var ref = database.ref('guestList')
  

    ref.on('value', readData, errData);
      }
    function readData(data){
      guestList=[];
      var scores = data.val();
      var keys = Object.keys(scores)
    
      for (var i=0; i < keys.length; i++){
        var k = keys[i]
        var name = scores[k].name;
        var inside = scores[k].Inside;
        var timeIn = scores[k].TimeIn;
        var timeOut = scores[k].TimeOut;
        guestList[i] = {
            name: name,
            Inside: inside,
            TimeIn: timeIn,
            TimeOut: timeOut,
        }
      }
      checkIn(guestList);
    }
    
    function errData(err){
      console.log('Error!');
      console.log(err);
    }
    //Helper Function to set text box to selected name
    function checkInn(name){
      console.log(name)
      document.getElementById('checkIn').value = name;
    }
    //Check in
    function checkIn(list) {

 
    //Grabs current guest to be added or deleted from form text box
    var name = document.getElementById('checkIn').value;

    //Checks to see if user is in list of guests and isn't in the list of guest in the party
    
    var guestsRef = firebase.database().ref("guestList/");

    guestsRef.orderByChild("name").on("child_added", function(data) {
    if (name == data.val().name) {
      objIndex = list.findIndex((obj => obj.name == name));
      guestsRef = firebase.database().ref("guestList/" + objIndex)
      guestsRef.update({
        Inside: "Yes",
        TimeIn: getTime(),
      })
      guestsRef.off();
      document.getElementById('checkIn').value = "";
      alerts(name, true)
    } 
  })
  }

    //------------------------- Check Out ------------------------------------------------------------
    //Helper Function to Grab current List index
    function printArrayy() {
      var ref = database.ref('guestList')
      ref.on('value', readOutData, errData);
      }
    function readOutData(data){
      guestList=[];
      var scores = data.val();
      var keys = Object.keys(scores)
    
      for (var i=0; i < keys.length; i++){
        var k = keys[i]
        var name = scores[k].name;
        var inside = scores[k].Inside;
        var timeIn = scores[k].TimeIn;
        var timeOut = scores[k].TimeOut;
        guestList[i] = {
            name: name,
            Inside: inside,
            TimeIn: timeIn,
            TimeOut: timeOut,
        }
      }
      checkOut(guestList);
    }
    
    //Helper Function to set text box to selected name
    function checkOutt(name){
      console.log(name);
      document.getElementById('checkOut').value = name;
    }
    //Check Out
    function checkOut(list) {
     
        //Grabs current guest to be added or deleted from form text box
        var name = document.getElementById('checkOut').value;
    
        //Checks to see if user is in list of guests and isn't in the list of guest in the party
        
        var guestsRef = firebase.database().ref("guestList/");
    
        guestsRef.orderByChild("name").on("child_added", function(data) {
        if (name == data.val().name) {
          objIndex = list.findIndex((obj => obj.name == name));
          guestsRef = firebase.database().ref("guestList/" + objIndex)
          guestsRef.update({
            Inside: "No",
            TimeOut: getTime(),
          })
          document.getElementById('checkOut').value = "";
          guestsRef.off();
          alerts(name, false)
        } 
      })
      }


//Placeholder to alert user when a succesful check in or check out function runs
  function alerts(name, Boolean){
    if(Boolean){
      console.log(name + " has been checked in!")
    }
    else{
      console.log(name + " has been checked out!")
    }
  }
```

[image]

Here is the screenshot of my output. Thanks in advance!
Edit: Forgot to mention and apologize for my excessive use of helper functions! My HTML form calls printArrayy() and printArray first for each function!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried once instep on, i mean:
`ref.once('value', readOutData, errData); }`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.